# Vuex Nuxt.js アクション内でstateが取得できない

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

アクション内でストアに格納されているstateを取得したいのですが、state名を指定すると、画像のような空の状態で取得できません。

何が原因で取得できないのでしょうか？

[image: ログの結果]

store/blog.js

```js
export const state = () => {
  return {
    blogs: [], // ブログ記事一覧を格納
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getBlog (state, paylaod) {
    console.log(state) // 取得できている
    console.log(state.blogs) // 取得できない
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actionの第一引数はミューデータのようなstateではなくcontextではないでしょうか。

```
getBlog ({ state }, paylaod) {
```

のように取り出せば期待されてる挙動は実現できるかと思われます。（アクションなので実際にはcommit等も使うでしょうが。）